# Save pandas csv to sub-directory

Tags: python, csv, pandas, filepath

I am trying to save the output of the following code to a subdirectory:

```
for gp in g:
    filename = gp[0] + '.csv'
    print(filename)
    gp[1].to_csv(filename)
```

I have created the subdirectory first:

```
os.makedirs('MonthlyDataSplit')
```

But I can't find any information as to how to use `to_csv` to save to a subdirectory rather than the current directory. One approach I was thinking was to use the `with "MonthlyDataSplit" open as directory` but I can only find the equivalent for opening a file in a subdirectory.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically you can build a path including subdirectories and pass this as the path arg to `to_csv`:

```
root = 'MonthlyDataSplit'
for gp in g:
    filename = gp[0] + '.csv'
    print(filename)
    gp[1].to_csv(root + '/' + filename)
```

You need to add slash separators to indicator what is a directory name and what is a filename, I would propose using `os.path.join` to simplify this process:

```
In [3]:
import os
root = 'MonthlyDataSplit'
os.path.join(root, 'some_file.csv')

Out[3]:
'MonthlyDataSplit\\some_file.csv'
```

For further subdirectories you can just add a new level:

```
In [8]:
import os
root = 'MonthlyDataSplit'
day = 'Day'
subdir = os.path.join(root, day)
final_path = os.path.join(subdir, 'some_file_name')
final_path

Out[8]:
'MonthlyDataSplit\\Day\\some_file_name'
```